# How to use HTTP headers in Nginx to serve different content?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http

I noticed that Deno serves `html` or `javascript` depending on the HTTP `accept` header.

For example if you simply open in your browser this package you will get HTML back (because the `accept` header is set to `accept: text/html`

https://deno.land/std@0.81.0/http/server.ts

But if you are using javascript to import it or even curl then you will get back a `javascript/typescript` file instead.

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.81.0/http/server.ts";
```

or `curl https://deno.land/std@0.81.0/http/server.ts`

This is really cool but I'm wondering how can I do this using Nginx? Without using Node.js or PHP. I know that I can specify server_name and location but what about headers?

For example if HTTP header is `accept: text/html` then proxy to server 1 otherwise proxy pass to a different server.

I'm looking for something like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.test.io;

    location / {
        IF HTTP HEADER accept == "text/html" {
            proxy_pass http://your_server_ip:443;
        } else {
            proxy_pass http://your_server_ip:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of mapping is done with nginx `map` directive.

Add the following map to your `http` level:

```
map $http_accept $upstream {
    default 192.168.100.1:8000;
    text/html 192.168.100.1:443;
}
```

Then, in your `server` block use:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
}
```

However, the `Accept` header often contains more than one MIME type, therefore the match part in the `map` needs to be more complex in reality.

For example, one might need to check if the header contains `text/html` at any point:

```
map $http_accept $upstream {
    ~.*text/html.* 192.168.100.1:443;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tero, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: I suppose this wouldn't work correctly. A typical `Accept` header sent by a browser looks more complex than simply `text/html`, e.g. `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`

Comment: Good point, I'll amend the answer.

Comment: I could not find anywhere in the documentation a list of all available HTTP header variables... ($http_accept, $http_origin, $http_content_type) Is there an official list?

Comment: I just used Google with keyword `http header`, and the first article is Mozilla MDN article on HTTP headers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers. There are headers that are standardised in various RFC's. I addition to that, there are many custom headers individual applications use.